# Why is HTML position: fixed; work like this

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I learn HTML and now this about [position: fixed;](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed)

Open that link and change `right: 0;` to any value and run it will only make it jump to other side of window.
I try sett right 1,2, 10, 50 and same effect.

I thought `right: 0;` could be used to fine tune location on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because by setting `right: 10` there is no unit for the value. So the browser just ignores it. You can try it with something like `right: 10px` and then it will work properly. For more about css units click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)